# How to work with tables in MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I try to get data from table use MapBasic:

```
Dim nCol = "ColumnName"
Fetch First From Untitled
Do While Not EOT(Untitled)
  colValue = Selection.nCol
Note colValue
Fetch Next From Untitled
Loop
```

Compilation ends success but when i start application in MapInfo get error:

```
Not defined Selection.nCol
```

How to work with columns in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use an alias, something like this (untested)

```
Dim nCol as alias
Fetch First From Untitled
Do While Not EOT(Untitled)
    nCol = Untitled + ".ColumnName"
    colValue = nCol
    Note colValue
    Fetch Next From Untitled
Loop
```

Comment: If your table name as well as your column are hard coded, you don't need an Alias variable, you can just refer to the combination of these two names: Untitled.ColumnName. If one of them is a variable, you need to go thru an Alias variable

Comment: Also quick note that if you can't hardcode a column name, you can get columns dynamically by column number like `.col2` or `.col(2)`